# Sharing Button for Care Program Object in Health Cloud Not Visible

Tags: lightning, sharing, health-cloud, classic

We are using HealthCloud for one of our project. Below is the configuration for Care Program in our org:

- The OWD for Care Program is set to Private
- The Sharing button has been added to the Care Program Page layout

The Sharing button is visible in classic page for Care Program. But, we can't see it on Lightning Record page as below:

**Classic View with Sharing Button:**
[image]

**Lightning View with No Sharing Button:**

[image]

Below screenshot shows, **OWD private for Care Program** object:
[image]

Below screenshot shows, **page layout configuration**:
[image]

**Question:**
**Is there something which we are missing or is this a known issue? If someone else also faced similar issue. Please suggest a solution or workaround for the same.**